# How to remove the Use different apple id option while implementing Sign in with apple in Reactjs + React Native App?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement Sign in with apple
My tech stack of frontend include React Native + the Reactjs

Problem is that I want to remove the `Use a different Apple Id` option as shown in the images below

1st one is of Binance which has removed the option that I'm talking about
2nd one is my app where this option is coming

[image]

[image]

I read the full documentation of apple developer but found nothing

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1):

This is strange because in Apple docs you can see `Use a different Apple Id`
[image]

But everywhere else you can not find `Use a different Apple Id`

I think it is related to debug, if you are on debug you can use different account for testing.. you can confirm this easily.

Comment: What do you mean when you say debug here? Please elaborate a bit

Comment: @Abhishek I mean that it is not a release version. Try to test it via TestFlight from another phone.